# Prevent Google Sheets function from running if a second instance of a spreadsheet is opened

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Current spreadsheet is shared between ~100 users as editors

Currently have an onOpen() function that calls a sortSheet() function (and a few others not of concern here.

The sortSheet() is executed every time the workbook is opened.  So a current user will see their sheet sorted when a second user opens it up.

Looking for a way to prevent the sortSheet() from running if the workbook has been already opened by someone else.

Something like:

```
function onOpen(e){
  if (workbook is not open by anyone else) {
   sortSheet()
  }
 do other important stuff that should happen no matter how many concurrent instances....
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling the `sortSheet` function on the `onOpen` function, it would be possible that the `sortSheet` function is called from a custom menu? - is there any reason this function is called once the spreadsheet is open?

Comment: understanding more about the use case and what you’re trying to accomplish will help us find you a better answer—can you provide more details? If this sheet is shared with 100+ editors and you sort on open ONLY IF no one else has it open, that condition is unlikely to ever be triggered with someone people potentially having it up at any given time. What is being sorted? Is it specific to a given user or can that range just always be sorted?

Comment: It really sorts two different sheets.  New records (rows) added from a web page, or has new records (rows) entered by a designated user.  Both require further data input by that user.  All others restricted to changing limited cells in either.  Most rejected using a menu option to sort, or a macro button.  When anyone else opens it up, screens jump 
 between the two sheets for all, until the sort is done.  And they loose their place after the sort.  Trying to minimize confusion for others, while telling the designated user "It only sorts with the first open'  She likes that idea....